# hadoop copy or move

Tags: hadoop, copy

I need copy/move from within HDFS to another location within the same HDFS but the destination's directory is different from the source.

Example:

> source: 
>   /warehouse/elephant/f_transactions_report/date=2012-12-01/9182837475_report_2012-12-01_processed.csv.gz
>   /warehouse/elephant/f_transactions_report/date=2012-12-02/9182837475_report_2012-12-02_processed.csv.gz
>   /warehouse/elephant/f_transactions_report/date=2012-12-03/9182837475_report_2012-12-03_processed.csv.gz...

> Destination:
>   /warehouse/elephant/f_transactional_events/date=2012-12-01/9182837475_report_2012-12-01_processed.csv.gz
>   /warehouse/elephant/f_transactional_events/date=2012-12-02/9182837475_report_2012-12-02_processed.csv.gz
>   /warehouse/elephant/f_transactional_events/date=2012-12-03/9182837475_report_2012-12-03_processed.csv.gz...

A new requirement caused a change in name in the source from f_transactions_report to f_transactional_events. Data stoped populating in the former, but continued in the latter. The problem now is to backfill the old (source) up to the switch over. How can this be done while maintaining file structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my own question!
1. hadoop get all dates by directory and save locally. e.g.
    hadoop fs -get /warehouse/elephant/f_transactions_report/date=2012-12* ~/elephant

2. Hadoop put back all locally saved directory back to new destination. e.g. 
    hadoop fs -put ~/elephant /warehouse/elephant/f_transactional_events/

The directory structure will remain the same. Check for validity!